# SSL Cert. Not found EAP

Tags: java, linux, ssl, wildfly

My Scenario:

I have 2 different keystores(A.jks and B.jks) which are used for SSL connections to two different servers. These keystores work from the command line when doing "smoke-tests".

Using an EAP server, if the call to web-service A (Using A.jks) happens before web-service B(Using B.jks), then web-service A is successful and web-service B is unsuccessful - resulting with **SSLHandshakeException**. This error also happens when the order is reversed..ie. call to web-service B (Using B.jks) happens before web-service call A(Using A.jks), then web-service B is successful and web-service A is unsuccessful.

Question: What would cause the KeyStores loaded in the Server context to override each other?

Comment: Can't you just store the certificates of both servers in a single keystore?

Comment: Have tried that,  still the same error.

Comment: Are you doing two-way SSL with client auth, or are those keystores only containing the distant servers public certificates?

Comment: It's is two way SSL...

Comment: I have turned on ssl debugging on the application server. The results of the stacktrace is: certificate_unknown.

Comment: One of my colleagues had a similar case recently, but I don't remember how it was solved... I think I can remember that when the key alias isn't specified, the WS connector will pick the first key that works and remember it.

Comment: I'm not sure I can help you much further, but maybe you'd have better results posting your question on https://developer.jboss.org/en/products/eap (or better RedHat's support if you have access).

Comment: Thank you. I will double check the alias.

Comment: The alias is not a problem, it's that you identify yourself with the same key to both servers, while they know you with different identities. The first time you connect to a server, JBoss choose an appropriate key to identify itself, but then it'll use this one for every other calls, while it should use another key when communicating with the other server

Answer (score 2):

Wildfly/ EAP does not play well with multiple TrustStores. Add the Certs. to one TrustStore and load that. This solution worked for me.